# Variable that contains Brackets causes problems

Tags: javascript, html

Easy stuff: I read the value of an select box when clicking on a Button and writing it into a text field:

The Select box:

```
<select name="link[link_category]">
  <option value="Fun">Sport</option>
  <option value="Music">Music</option>
</select>
```

Now I have my button

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Continue</button>
```

that triggers a simple function

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
  result = document.new_link.link[link_category].value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result;
}
</script>
```

result reads the value from the select box and the function outputs the value in a field called "demo"

```
<p id="demo"></p>
```

My Problem:

Using a simple name for the  Box like "abc" makes everything work like a charm. But as soon as using brackets (I need brackets for my rails app to work) it says

*Uncaught ReferenceError: link_category is not defined*

How can I use brackets to work with my JS function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use `document.forms['new_link'].elements['link[link_category]'].value` as it is the correct way to get form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use bracket notation to access it

```
result = document.new_link['link[link_category]'].value;
```

Comment: perfect. you're awesome!